# Reading and changing form' action using jQuery in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-events

I have a jQuery code as follows:

```
function changeSomething(event) {
    var url = $(event.target).closest("form").attr("action");
}
```

My problem is `$(event.target).closest("form").attr("action")` is not reading the action attribute on IE (IE8) though it works perfectly on other browsers (i.e.: Chrome and Firefox). And I don't have any tags named "action" or "submit". So this problem can't be generated from it. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: have you tested if `$(event.target).closest("form")` returns the correct form in IE8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this check to your code:

```
 var url;
 if (typeof event.target != 'undefined'){
  url = $(event.target).closest("form").attr("action");
 }
 else{
  url = $(event.srcElement).closest("form").attr("action");
 }
```

I am not sure if `event.target` is supported by IE8

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanx :). It works. Seems like I'll have to change every, 'event.target' in my code. :-/

Comment: This can be simplified to `$(event.target || event.srcElement)`.

Comment: Yeah, great addition pimvb! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It may be helpfull...

```
ver elem = (typeof event.target == 'undefined')?e.currentTarget? event.target;
var url = $(elem).closest("form").attr("action");
```